# Eliminating words from a list if these words contain a letter not present in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a sentence with only lowercase letters and no spaces, for example:

```
sentence = "markeatsbread"
```

and a list of words, for example:

```
b_list = ["yogurt","read","beam","drake","june","fire"]
```

I want to create a function which generates a new list that doesn't contain words which couldn't be anagrams of the sentence written above.

I tried this:

```
def list_reducer(sentence,b_list):
count = 0
g_list = []
for word in b_list:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] not in sentence:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            if count == len(word):
                g_list.append(word)       
return g_list
```

For some reasons that code doesn't work since g_list only contains:

```
["read"]
```

While the correct result should be this:

```
["read","beam","drake"]
```

It's been days but I still can't figure out where's the mistake in my code. 
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't reset count for each new word, so it is always increasing.
Move the count assignment to inside the for loop.

```
def list_reducer(sentence, b_list):
g_list = []
for word in b_list:
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] not in sentence:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            if count == len(word):
                g_list.append(word)       
return g_list
```

Or, you could remove count and just use i from the loop.

```
def list_reducer(sentence, b_list):
g_list = []
for word in b_list:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] not in sentence:
            break
        else:
            if i == len(word)-1:
                g_list.append(word)       
return g_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now it works. But can I ask why did you write "if count == len(word)-1:" instead of "if count == len(word):" ?

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry, that was a mistake from trying the second solution, it should be "if count == len(word):"